# How to convert the date set from DD:MM:YY HH::MM to morning, afternoon, evening, night in quicksights?

Tags: amazon-quicksight

Hi i column in quick sights in the following format:
21/01/2022 9AM
27/01/2022 8pm
4/02/2022 2PM
and so on.
I want to change them morning, afternoon and night in amazon quicksights. I tried everything that is available in internet but nothing worked for me. As there is HOUR function in quicksight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `extract('HH', {date})` function to extract the hour portion from your date field. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/extract-function.html
Then you can use an `ifelse()` logic to classify the time into day periods.

Example, if your field is called `{date}`, then you could try something like this:

```
ifelse(
  extract('HH', {date}) < 6, 'NIGHT',
  extract('HH', {date}) < 12, 'MORNING',
  extract('HH', {date}) < 17, 'ATERNOON',
  extract('HH', {date}) < 20, 'EVENING',
  'NIGHT'
)
```